# CKEditor custom style that inserts a heading with an anchor

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ckeditor

I would like to enable the user to insert a heading that has an anchor inside. Like this:

```
<h1 style="border-image: none;">
   <a name="aName" id="aId">
     Selected text becomes a heading with an anchor
   </a>
</h1>
```

This I can already reach by using the plugins Format (or Styles) for creating a heading and then Anchor. It would be more comfortable to have a combined solution (e.g.) within the Styles-dropdown (or Format). Is this even possible or would I have write a new plugin for that?

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: did you try medium editor?? it looks great and also provides a ton of functionality..

Comment: Any modern browser accepts an ID as a valid anchor target, there is no need for an a tag.

Comment: Try using `document.execCommand("heading", false, "h1")` followed by `document.execCommand("createLink", false, url)` Not sure if it will work, just a thought. Also, the user must have the text selected when the commands are run, and the document must have `designMode` on (if you don't want this for your main document use an iframe).

Comment: @ Aman Arora Thanks for advice. It looks pretty leightweighted.